# How can one type hint a __new__ method implementation using a Generic or Union?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, mypy, typing

How can I type hint my `__new__` implementation using a generic input?

So I have a class that can store `str` or `decimal.Decimal` instances, and it subclasses the input `str` or `decimal.Decimal` class.

This code works in mypy and python:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import typing
import typing_extensions
import decimal
import random

T = typing.TypeVar('T', str, decimal.Decimal)

class StrOrDecimal(typing.Generic[T]):
    @typing.overload
    def __new__(cls, arg: decimal.Decimal) -> StrOrDecimalTyped.Decimal.StrOrDecimal[decimal.Decimal]:
        ...
    @typing.overload
    def __new__(cls, arg: str) -> StrOrDecimalTyped.Str.StrOrDecimal[str]:
        ...
    # def __new__(cls, arg: typing.Union[str, decimal.Decimal]): does not work
    def __new__(cls, arg):  # works
        if isinstance(arg, decimal.Decimal):
            return super(cls, StrOrDecimalTyped.Decimal.StrOrDecimal).__new__(StrOrDecimalTyped.Decimal.StrOrDecimal, arg)
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            return super(cls, StrOrDecimalTyped.Str.StrOrDecimal).__new__(StrOrDecimalTyped.Str.StrOrDecimal, arg)
        raise ValueError('Invalid value')

_StrOrDecimal = StrOrDecimal
# needed for mypy
class StrOrDecimalTyped:
    class Str:
        class StrOrDecimal(_StrOrDecimal[T], str):
            pass
    class Decimal:
        class StrOrDecimal(_StrOrDecimal[T], decimal.Decimal):
            pass

a_val = 'a'
a = StrOrDecimal(a_val)
print(a)

b_val = decimal.Decimal('1.2')
b = StrOrDecimal(b_val)
print(b)

choices: typing.List[typing.Union[str, decimal.Decimal]] = [a_val, b_val]
c_val = random.choice(choices)
c = StrOrDecimal(c_val)

try:
    reveal_type(a)
    reveal_type(b)
    reveal_type(c)
except NameError:
    typing_extensions.reveal_type(a)
    typing_extensions.reveal_type(b)
    typing_extensions.reveal_type(c)
```

But if I use either of these signatures:

```
def __new__(cls, arg: typing.Union[str, decimal.Decimal]):
def __new__(cls, arg: T):
```

I get this error:

> generic.py:19: error: Argument 1 to "__new__" of "StrOrDecimal" has incompatible type "Type[generic.StrOrDecimalTyped.Decimal.StrOrDecimal[Any]]"; expected "Type[generic.StrOrDecimal[T]]"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, seems that you've just discovered a `mypy` bug, because `pyright` works as expected here. Consider reporting at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Comment: Filed it here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15220